# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException in struts2

Tags: jakarta-mail

i am getting issue with sending email in struts2. error is **javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException** in struts2

code :

```
static Properties properties = new Properties();
    static {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

}

Comment: You supplied the wrong username or password.  Start [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).

Comment: Check if username/password are valid. If you are getting this with valid credentials check - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37051787/1986826