# Java Send Email via gmail

Tags: java, gmail, send

The following code is supposed to send email via gmail but it gives the following error:

[image]

On my gmail account I get a message that a sign in was prevented and I should use a secure app like gmail to access my account. The source code is as shown below:

```
public void doSendMail(){
    username = txtFrom.getText();
    password= new String(txtPassword.getPassword());
    to = txtTo.getText();
    subject = txtSubject.getText();
    email_body = jTextArea1.getText();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
    }
    );
    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(email_body);
        Transport.send(message);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message Sent!","Sent",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
    }
}
```

What can I do to the code to make it send mail via gmail?

Comment: Could you post the text of error messages which can be copied?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37051208/javamail-works-with-jboss-application-server-7-but-not-working-with-tomcat7-on-o/37051787#37051787

Comment: I set the error caught by try...catch block to be displayed on a message dialog. I believe the error is shown on the message dialog I posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your source code is perfect for sending email via gmail. May be you have to allow your account for less secure access via `https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps`

Here is your code. I made very little modification to run as standalone program. It requires two jars : 1) mail-1.4.7.jar and 2) activation-1.1.1.jar

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *  Following jar are required:
 *  1) mail-1.4.7.jar from http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.7/mail-1.4.7.jar
 *  2) activation-1.1.1.jar from http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar
 *
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("gmail username: ");
        String username = sc.next();
        System.out.print("gmail password: ");
        String password = sc.next();
        System.out.print("destination email address: ");
        String to = sc.next();
        System.out.print("subject: ");
        String subject = sc.next();
        System.out.print("email body: ");
        String email_body = sc.next();
        Test test = new Test();
        test.doSendMail(username, password, to, subject, email_body);
        sc.close();

    }
    // sends mail
    public void doSendMail(final String username, final String password, String to, String subject, String email_body) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(email_body);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("message sent");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message Sent!", "Sent", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tend to think that that may be the issue, but what does the activation-1.1.1.jar do?

Comment: I used javax.swing.mail.jar version 1.5.5

Comment: Worked after turning on less secure apps. Thanks @Sanjeev Saha

Comment: Did not worked: **javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.xyz.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect**

Comment: @ShamimAhmad your stack trace is showing that your are using `mail.smtp.host=smtp.xyz.com`, this is wrong!!! you should use `mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com`. Please compare your values with the values given in this program. It should work.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha I just did not exposed my SMTP host address, it is actually `mail.smtp.host=smtp.<myhost>.com`

Comment: @ShamimAhmad Please copy the code from here and run it on your environment. If you are not able to send mail, then the problem is related to system administration. You should talk with `sys-admins`.

Answer (score 0):

for me is working using this properties:

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: got the same message OscarBcn

Comment: do you have this activated? https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Comment: I did that and it worked, that was actually the issue, did not alter my source code

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendMailSSL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String to = "krishna14581@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

        //Get the session object  
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("yourgmailid@gmail.com", "password");//change accordingly  
            }
        });

        //compose message  
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("yourgmailid@gmail.com"));//change accordingly  
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Hello");
            message.setText("Testing.......");

            //send message  
            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("message sent successfully");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: got the same message but it's working for yahoo when you change the hos to "smtp.mail.yahoo.com".

Comment: try "smtp-relay.gmail.com" as host.

Comment: I turned on access for less secure apps on google and it worked just fine. No need to alter the code

Answer (score 0):

just go to: https://myaccount.google.com/security 
    go to bottom of page and enable: Allow less secure apps