# Can not sent email through java programm

Tags: java, smtp, jms, jakarta-mail

Tried number of options found on google including stackoverflow but did not succeed:

```
package net.codejava.spring;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String to = "abc@gmail.com";
        String from = "info@xyz.com";

        // Get the session object
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.xyz.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("info@xyz.com", "test999");
            }
        });

        // compose the message
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Ping");
            message.setText("Hello, this is example of sending email  ");

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("message sent successfully....");

        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried all I could do with it, please help me on this. Also, tried this one but failure again,

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/unable-to-send-mail-due-to-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-297665338.html

Comment: Google changed some part of their API for gmail, check their documentation. The last time I tried on gmail it failed but it worked for all my other mails. They say they have a more secure one now.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use google API, trying to use my own email server.

Comment: It's just that I have sent an email on google email id, its not like I am using google API to send email.

Comment: Could you please look at the accepted answer given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495808/java-send-email-via-gmail/37496125#37496125

Comment: Try by putting direct IP address for SMTP HOST.

Comment: @PVR Issues remains the same even after using direct IP address.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha Did not work

Comment: Hi @ShamimAhmad have you allowed your gmail account for `less secure apps` ? If you do not do that you will not be able to send mail. Please copy the program from the accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495808/java-send-email-via-gmail/37496125#37496125 and run that on your system.

Comment: Please fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and then post the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing the failure.

Comment: Issue resolve! It was just a network administrator permission issue. It is working fine now.